# Keycloak id_token is null with REST authentication

Tags: java, authentication, wildfly, keycloak

While using REST authentication with Keycloak, my id_token is null (server side). To connect to the application, I am using the following URI:`http://localhost:port/auth/realms/{name}/protocol/openid-connect/token` provided in the documentation (with the appropriate form params grant_type, username, password,... see [here](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/direct-access-grants.html)). In response (client side) I can retrieve the **access_token** and **id_token**. Then, I am using the "Bearer" authorization in the HTTP header to discuss with the server. While using my custom client, the **id_token** is null in the server side. 
Can someone explain me why?

(Just to be clear, all is working well by using the keycloak authentication page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the **id_token** is only used while using the GUI authentication interface. To bypass my problem, I added my custom metadata to the **access_token**, then replaced all the reference to the **id_token** (on server side) to the **access_token**. By doing this, the application is fully compatible with the OAuth2 protocol.